# Can I play a card to move out of a player's property and avoid paying rent?

Tags: monopoly

When you land on someone’s space and they own that space, instead of paying rent can you just use a card that says move to any space. Like you can move somewhere a else while it is still your turn.

Answer (score 13):

The only cards which move you to another space are Chance and Community Chest cards. All of those cards take effect immediately upon drawing them and they are discarded, aside from the *Get out of jail free* cards (which you keep). Thus, it is impossible for you to have a card that moves you to another space, unless you are in jail - and you are not paying rent to anyone in jail...

Comment: Have to admit, that would make it a pretty cool house-rule to let those move cards be kept and played at any time, although it removes the downside because if someone has a hotel on Boardwalk all you have to do is choose to not move there...

Comment: @corsiKa, Would make more sense to be able to use them before rolling. In the scenario you presented, the player did land on Boardwalk and thus owes rent.

Comment: @ikegami I think that'd be a good way around that problem, yeah.

Comment: @corsika this would reduce the dangers of cards that move the player to an expensive property when they are short on cash and in general that goes against the game and is a type of house rule that makes the game last for hours.

Comment: @JoeW As I said, "it removes the downside because if someone has a hotel..." - yes, I agree if not properly developed it's the kind that make the game drag out. Although most of those house rules exist specifically so no one can lose because little kids don't like to lose. Who would have thought having little kids play a game designed to illustrate the devastating effects of capitalism would cause those kids to cry?!